# How to change the UIButton color in iOS based on selection? for the specified UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am working on a tab like appearance in `ios 7`, am not able to make the selection of button to change its colour. i have already tried setting the different colours for each state.

i want to know how can i change the selected button to a colour and all other buttons to black colour.

Comment: can you please share your code,..

Comment: Are you want to change the background colour for specified Button state,..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant get what you are exactly looking for, Try this it will hopefully helps you,..

```
- (IBAction)clickButton:(id)sender {

if (button.state == UIControlStateHighlighted) {

     [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor COLOR_YOU_WANT]];

     (or)

     [button setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor COLOR_YOU_WANT]] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

     (or)

     [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed@"ColourImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using images, you can use:

`[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed@"Collor1"] forState:(some state)];`

Where the state could be one of these:

```
UIControlStateDisabled
UIControlStateHighlighted
UIControlStateSelected
UIControlStateNormal
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor redColor]] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 0):

first you should use custom button, then on selection button you should use below code in target method :

```
[myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor YOUR_CHOICE_COLOR] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I hope it will work. If any clarification needed then let me know..